# My react app (login form) doesn't work like a spa page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I used CRA to create simple Login form. I've set up database with mongoose and built crud with node.
I don't think it has anything to do with the backend. 
My intention with this little boiler plate was:
(not logged in) -> landing page shows 'Welcome' with Home, sign in menu.
(logged in) -> landing page shows 'Welcome, name' with Home, MyPage menu.

Down below is Login.js.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import "../App.css";

function Login() {
  const [Email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [Password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [Error, setError] = useState("");

  const onEmailHandler = (e) => {
    setEmail(e.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const onPasswordHandler = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const body = {
      email: Email,
      password: Password,
    };

    axios
      .post("/api/users/login", body)
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.data.token) {
          setError(response.data.error);
        } else {
          window.location.replace("/");
          //props.history.push("/");
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <form className="login_form">
          <input
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            onChange={onEmailHandler}
            value={Email}
          />
          <br />
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            onChange={onPasswordHandler}
            value={Password}
          />
          <br />
          <button onClick={onSubmitHandler}>Login</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          marginTop: 14,
          fontSize: 15,
          color: "red",
          fontFamily: "Arial",
          fontWeight: "lighter",
        }}
      >
        {Error}
      </div>

      <div className="register_button">
        <Link to="/register">Sign Up</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

As you can see, when you are signed in properly you are thrown to the landing page.
landing page looks like this.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../App.css";
import axios from "axios";

function Landing() {
  const [Nickname, setNickname] = useState("");
  axios.get("/api/users/authenticate").then((response) => {
    if (response.data.name) {
      setNickname(response.data.name);
    }
  });

  return Nickname === "" ? (
    <div className="welcome_msg">
      <h4>Welcome!</h4>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div className="welcome_msg">
      <h4>Welcome, {Nickname}!</h4>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Landing;
```

And most importantly, App.js looks like down below.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";
import Landing from "./components/Landing";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import MyPage from "./components/MyPage";
import Register from "./components/Register";
function App() {
  const [IsLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  axios.get("/api/users/authenticate").then(
    (response) => {
      if (response.data.email) {
        setIsLoggedIn(true);
      } else {
        setIsLoggedIn(false);
      }
      console.log(IsLoggedIn);
    }
    //[IsLoggedIn]
  );

  return IsLoggedIn ? (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <nav className="navigate">
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <Link to="/mypage">Mypage</Link>
        <hr />
      </nav>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/mypage" component={MyPage} />
      <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  ) : (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <nav className="navigate">
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <Link to="/login">Sign in</Link>
        <hr />
      </nav>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/mypage" component={MyPage} />
      <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The Router api/user/authenticate returns json with user information(email, name, token).

It's not like there's an error to the app, but I think maybe it's re-rendered too many times? It's slow and doesn't work like a spa page. I've checked the network tab and there seems to be too many requests (mostly authentication) whenever i go to Home or Mypage.

Stay safe, stay away from virus and please help :(

Answer (score 0):

That's because the submit handler must be passed to the form itself as an onSubmit method instead of the onClick of the button.

```
<form className="login_form" onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
 ...
</form>
```